# If não funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um site, nele alguns usuários irão acessar e preciso que **a senha expire a cada 30 dias**. Fiz essa verificação, mas nunca cai nela, mesmo quando o if é verdadeiro. Se alguém tiver alguma ideia do que pode estar errado ou uma dica para melhorar, agradeço. Abaixo segue o código em **PHP**.

```
  $cnpj               = $_POST['cnpj'];
  $senha              = $_POST['senha'];
  $hoje               = date('Y-m-d');

  $conexao            = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or print(mysqli_error());
  $db                 = mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'teste') or print(mysqli_error());

  $sql                = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj' AND senha = '$senha'";
  $sql2               = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = 'expirou' WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj' and NOW() > data_senha"; 
  $sql3               = "UPDATE usuario SET data_senha = NOW() WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj'";
  $sql4               = "SELECT data_senha FROM usuario WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj'";

  $resultado_login    = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
  $data_senha         = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql4);

  if ($hoje >= $data_senha) {
    echo "<script> window.alert('Sua senha expirou! Entre em contato com a Rofran e solicite a nova senha.'); </script>";
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../index.html'); </script>";
    $update_senha       = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql2);
    $update_data_senha  = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql3);
  }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_login) == 0){
    header("Location: ../erro.html");
    session_destroy();    
  }else{
    header("Location:../home.html");
    session_start();
  }
```

Testei ambas as variáveis de data e retornam valor, mas nestes testes também percebi que não são do mesmo tipo, mesmo apresentando o mesmo formato yyyy-mm-d.

Comment: As variáveis $hoje e $data_senha são do mesmo tipo?

Comment: você já tentou isso `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($resultado));die;` antes do if. Já tentou colocar um `die("alguma coisa");` dentro dos blocos do IF, para ver se realmente não está entrado, ou se o código dentro é que não funciona?

Comment: Não é possível verificar se é maior data_senha. Não é número inteiro.

Comment: Primeira coisa, seu código não vai chegar até o if? Pois você redireciona antes... já verificou? O data senha pelo seu código é apenas uma string, esqueceu de executar os comandos...

Comment: Sim, mas ao iniciar essa implementação a primeira vez que fiz deu certo, caiu no if. Agora não acontece mais e se coloco antes da verificação também não funciona

Comment: Veja o $data_senha... só tem um comando sql nela...

Comment: Sim, pois essa data vem do banco

Comment: Para pegar a data vc precisa dar um mysqli_query e depois um mysqli_mysqli_fetch_assoc... http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Ok, obrigada pela dica. Irei corrigir

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52833/discussion-between-rodrigo-sartori-jarouche-and-r-gasparin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após a ajuda de @oeslei e @AntonioAntunes, alterei o código e está funcionando. Segue abaixo o código correto:

```
<?php 

  $cnpj                  = $_POST['cnpj'];
  $senha                 = $_POST['senha'];
  $hoje                  = date('Y-m-d');

  $conexao               = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or print(mysqli_error());
  $db                    = mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'teste') or print(mysqli_error());

  $sql                   = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj' AND senha = '$senha'";
  $sql2                  = "UPDATE usuario SET senha = 'expirou', data_senha = NOW() WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj' and NOW() > data_senha"; 
  $sql3                  = "SELECT data_senha FROM usuario WHERE cnpj = '$cnpj'";

  $resultado_login       = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
  $res_data_senha        = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conexao, $sql3));
  $data_senha            = $res_data_senha["data_senha"];

  if($hoje >= $data_senha){
    echo "<script> window.alert('Sua senha expirou! Entre em contato e solicite a nova senha.'); </script>";
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('../index.html'); </script>";
    $update_senha_data   = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2);
  }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_login) == 0){
    header("Location: ../erro.html");
    session_destroy();    
  }else{
    header("Location:../home.html");
    session_start();
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, temos alguns problemas nesse código.

O primeiro deles é o conteúdo de $data_senha. Ele sempre vai ser somente o texto da query, porque não há em momento algum a execução dela, nem a obtenção do resultado.

O segundo deles é que ao encontrar um registro na query, que está correta (a que localiza o usuário pelo cnpj e senha), ele já encaminha o cabeçalho HTTP que manda o browser redirecionar ao "home.html". Então, tudo que ocorrer a partir daí, o usuário não vai perceber - no caso as mensagens de alerta que seriam geradas ao corrigir o primeiro erro.

O terceiro deles é que as queries que deveriam executar ao final, dentro do if que verifica as datas, nunca são executadas. Você apenas as cria, como string, mas não há qualquer chamada ao método mysqli_query, que finalmente as executaria.

Corrigindo esses três, o seu código já deve funcionar.

Comment: Alterei como você sugeriu mas ainda não funciona, já mudei o código na pergunta. A primeira vez que testei deu certo, mas após testar a segunda já não funcionou mais

Comment: Em relação ao $data_senha, agora você executa a query, mas não há em momento algum a obtenção do resultado - utilize algo como mysqli_fetch_array utilizando o resource retornado pela mysqli_query, para popular um array e deste array acessar a informação que quer (a data).

Comment: Ok, irei testar. Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Considere esta parte do código:

```
// ...
$data_senha = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql4);
if ($hoje >= $data_senha) {
// ...
```

A variável `$data_senha` não possui o valor da data, e sim um objeto  [`MySQLi_Result`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php). Para obter o valor desejado, é necessário utilizar alguma função de `fetch`, como o [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), que retorna um array contendo os valores selecionados.

Além disso, como já observado em outra resposta, é necessário utilizar a função `strtotime` para comparar as datas.

Sendo assim..

```
// ...
$resultado_data_senha = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conexao, $sql4));
$data_senha = $resultado_data_senha["data_senha"];
if (strtotime($hoje) >= strtotime($data_senha)) {
// ...
```

Comment: strtotime não funciona, ocorre o seguinte erro: "strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", este erro ocorre porque após fazer o mysql_fetch_accoc do $data_senha, essa variável vira um array e não tem sentido fazer strtotime para um array.

Comment: Sem fazer strtotime, funciona o mysql_fetch_accoc, porém ele só funcionou com a data, então entra na condição if, mas os updates dentro do if que eu adaptei assim como fiz com a data não funcionam.

Comment: @R.Gasparin sobre a variável `$data_senha` ser um array deve-se ao fato de que é necessário obter o valor do índice `data_senha` como fiz na linha anterior à condição. Já para os updates, basta rodar o `mysqli_query`, não é necessário utilizar o retorno e muito menos executar um `fetch`.

Comment: No código da pergunta está com mysqli_query, mas acho que não funcionava pois fazia dois updates seguidos, agora fiz apenas um e finalmente está tudo funcionando agora. Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Faça essas alterações e veja se está caindo no IF.
Em baixo do $data_senha, coloque:

```
$resultado_data = mysqli_query($conexao, $data_senha);
$linha= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_data);
```

E substitua o if por:

```
if($hoje >= $linha['data_senha'])
```

Comment: Obrigada pela correção, irei tentar!

Comment: Não deu certo desta maneira que você sugeriu, continuarei tentando

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar datas deve-se usar assim:

```
If(strtotime($hoje) >= strtotime($data_senha)){ }
```

Comment: Não deu certo desta maneira que você sugeriu, continuarei tentando

Comment: Então o valor tá vindo diferente do banco.

Answer (score -2):

Uma boa maneira de debugar seria dar print nos dados da variável $data_senha e do retorno do mysql para verificar se a informação estão batendo.

Comment: Ambas as datas estão retornando valores quando testo, só não entendi que retorno mysql é esse que tu ta se referindo, poderia explicar?

Comment: da um echo $hoje e um echo $data_senha['data_senha'] e ve qual o formato de dados que elas retornam.

Outra maneira seria vc passar a data de hoje na query e validar no banco.

Exemplo: SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS brand_count FROM table WHRE id = ? AND data_senha <= now()

Dessa forma vc vai receber um boolean que sera passado no seu if(#linha['brand_count' == 1]) {}

Comment: Não é permitido usar o campo de respostas para fazer comentários. O recurso de comentário será disponibilizado para você quando você tiver mais reputação. Até lá utilize o campo de respostas apenas para responder a pergunta.

Comment: Ambas retornam data no formato yyyy-mm-d, mas acredito que ainda assim são tipos diferentes pois quando realizo um if $hoje !== $data_senha que é pra verificar se são tipos diferentes cai nesse if, então não sei como deixar do mesmo tipo